# Inserting a node into a Binary Search Tree

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11

I am trying to implement a simple C++ function that adds a node to a Binary Search Tree given the value of the node to be inserted, and the root of the BST.
Surprisingly, I am not able to push any element. Although I made sure that the statement where I am inserting the node is entered by the compiler, the tree did not have any of the nodes I am trying to add. I think the problem could be in how I am passing the node in the function argument. Anyone can help? Thank you.    Here's my Node type and the implementation of the function.

```
 struct Node{

    int value;
    Node *left;
    Node *right;
    };

    //this method adds a new node with value v to Binary Search Tree
    // node is initially the root of the tree
    void Push_To_BST(Node* node,int v)
    {

    // the right place to add the node
    if(node==NULL)
    {

    node=new Node();
    node->value= v;
    node->left= NULL;
    node->right=NULL;

    }

    //the value to be added is less than or equal the reached node
    else if(v <= node->value)
        {
    //adding the value to the left subtree
    Push_To_BST(node->left,v);
    }

    //the value to be added is greater than the reached node
    else if(v > node->value)
    {
    //adding the value to the right subtree
    Push_To_BST(node->right,v);
    }

    }
```

Comment: You should use the debugger to trace the activity of your program.

Comment: one problem is that else if (v <= node->value)
statement. If v==node->value, it shouldn't be added to the tree at all. BSTs cannot contain duplicates. So I would add an else to throw those away.

Comment: Or just drop the `=` from `else if(v <= node->value)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Careful with your referencing, there.

```
void Push_To_BST(Node* node,int v) 
{ 

// the right place to add the node 
if(node==NULL) 
{  
    node=new Node(); 
    // etc
```

The `node` you are allocating memory to is a *local* variable. You would need to pass in a `Node**` in order to pass *out* a pointer to a freshly created node.

Example:

```
void Push_To_BST(Node** pnode,int v) 
{ 
    Node* node = *pnode;

    // the right place to add the node 
    if(node==NULL) 
    {  
        node=new Node(); 
        // etc
    }
    else if(v < node->value)  
    {  
        //adding the value to the left subtree  
        Push_To_BST(&node->left,v);  
    }  
    // etc
```

and call it like

```
Node* n = new Node;
Push_To_BST(&n, 2);
```

Comment: As an addendum, consider using `std::shared_ptr<Node>` instead of `Node*` in the interest of sensible automated memory management.

Comment: Thank you Rook....but when I pass it to the arguments as Node** I am getting a compiler error? Is there any further modifications I need to add in the code? Can you please send me the whole part modified? Thank you.

Comment: Part of the code inline. You can adapt the rest easily enough ;-)

Comment: `Node*&` would be a lot easier to work with (i.e., less dereferencing).

Answer (score 0):

You are allocating a new node and filling it in, but never changing a pointer in an existing node to point to the new node.